# AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget for Lambda ProvisionedConcurrency not working as expected

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

My Lambda has a spike of traffic daily at the same time. I want to have a set number of provisioned instances available at that time and the scale back down 5 minutes later.

I thought this could be achieved through CloudFormation and `AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget` but the results are not as expected.

To test how that configuration item works I created up a small test Lambda function (just a HelloWorld.java with a 15 seconds sleep; code at the bottom) and the CloudFormation template below that should spin up 10 instances every 4th minute, and scale back down every 6th minute.

I opened 19 browser tabs opened on the AWS console Lambda Function, and "Tested" my function. Basically hitting my function quickly so that new instances need to be spun up (because of the internal 15 second sleep).

I used Cloudwatch to graph the `ConcurrentExecutions` and the `ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions`. I was expecting to see the `ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions` go up to 20 at 14:28,32,36... and scale back down at 14:30,34,48...

I don't see *any* `ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions` in the metrics.

Do I misunderstand how this works, or did I get the CloudFormation wrong?

[image]

**CloudFormation Template**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Provision test

Globals:
  Function:
    AutoPublishAlias: live
    DeploymentPreference:
      Type: AllAtOnce

Parameters:
  Stage: {Type: String, Default: ''}
  UseBatsKeyParam: {Type: String, Default: 'false', AllowedValues: ['true','false']}
  DeploymentBucketImportName:
    Type: String
    Default: "DeploymentBucket"
Conditions:
  UseBatsKey:
    'Fn::Equals':
      - {Ref: UseBatsKeyParam}
      - 'true'

Resources:

  # Lambda function
  HelloWorld:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: 'com.example.lambda.demo.Hello::handleRequest'
      Runtime: java8.al2
      Description: "Hello World"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 900
      CodeUri:
        # Why are we using this instead of BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket?
        # Simply put, chicken and egg.
        # BATS::SAM::S3Bucket just falls back to a pipeline parameter. Problem is, we can't know that bucket name at synthesis time.
        # So we just import it.
        Bucket: {'Fn::If' : ['UseBatsKey', 'BATS::SAM::CodeS3Bucket', {"Fn::ImportValue" : {Ref: 'DeploymentBucketImportName'}}]}
        Key: BATS::SAM::CodeS3Key
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt: [LambdaRole, Arn]
  LambdaRole:
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [lambda.amazonaws.com]
        Version: '2012-10-17'
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role

  TestFunctionConcurrency:
    Type: 'AWS::ApplicationAutoScaling::ScalableTarget'
    Properties:
      MaxCapacity: 100
      MinCapacity: 3
      ResourceId: !Sub 'function:${HelloWorld}:live'
      RoleARN:
        Fn::Sub: 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/aws-service-role/lambda.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com/                                               AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_LambdaConcurrency'
      ScalableDimension: 'lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency'
      ServiceNamespace: lambda
      ScheduledActions:
        - ScalableTargetAction:
            MinCapacity: 20
          Schedule: 'cron(*/4 * * * ? *)'
          ScheduledActionName: scale-out
        - ScalableTargetAction:
            MinCapacity: 3
            MaxCapacity: 3
          Schedule: 'cron(2-59/4 * * * ? *)'
          ScheduledActionName: scale-in
    DependsOn: HelloWorldAliaslive

Outputs:
  StackArn:
    Value:
      Ref: AWS::StackId
    Description: Use this as the stack_arn in your cloud_formation_deployment_stack override.
```

**Lambda Function Code**

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {

```
@Override
public String handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
    try {
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);
    return "Hello from Lambda asfter 30 seconds: " + input;
}
```

}

Comment: The giant break in `RoleARN` is actually in your code?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that! I'm shocked that AWS even let me create a stack with such a glaring mistake. I'll deployed a new stack with a fix and retested but still the same results. I've updated my question.